# A dynamic drop down box with cakephp

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I am learning PHP and I had a project which is "creation if website for Riads' reservation".
 After implementing the backend, I've needed to create a dynamic drop down for : 
- When adding a new product, the admin has to choose a specific road and then the room's box should update with only the room that belong to this riad.
This is my code :

in the view product - admin_add.ctp :

```
$this->Js->get('#ProductRiadId')->event('change', 
$this->Js->request(array(
    'controller'=>'rooms',
    'action'=>'getByRiad'
    ), array(
    'update'=>'#ProductRoomId',
    'async' => true,
    'method' => 'post',
    'dataExpression'=>true,
    'data'=> $this->Js->serializeForm(array(
        'isForm' => true,
        'inline' => true
        ))
    ))
);
```

In the Productcontroller :

```
public $helpers = array('Js');
```

in the RoomsConroller :

```
public function getByRiad() {

    $this->layout = false
    $riad_id = $this->request->data['Product']['riad_id'];

    $rooms = $this->Riad->find('list', array(
        'conditions' => array('Room.riad_id' => $riad_id),
        'recursive' => -1
        ));

    $this->set('riads',$riads);
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
}
```

When I charge the page, the room box is empty, could you please tell me what's the problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you making sure that jquery is included in the layout that admin_add uses and are outputting the buffer. The cookbook details many of the details. Also, use a browser debug tool like chrome developer or firefox firebug to see if the ajax call is even happening.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I install firebug and these are the errors that it shows me :
<h2>Fatal Error</h2>
<p class="error">
 <strong>Error: </strong>
 syntax error, unexpected &#039;$riad_id&#039; (T_VARIABLE) <br>

 <strong>File: </strong>
 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/site-riads-new/app/Controller/RoomsController.php <br>

 <strong>Line: </strong>
 31</p>
<p class="notice">